# setOnDismissListener can i know which button i click in android

Tags: android

```
sbpOfScreen.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        // How to know what button I click?
                    }
                });
```

I have `sbpOfScreen` instance of `DialogPreference`. And I would like to know what I click. I am using setOnDismissListener. How can I know if I click `"Ok"` or `"Cancel"`?

Comment: Why don't you just set your DialogInterface.OnClickListener() on the individual buttons - position and negative?

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment -

```
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(activity.getString(R.string.ok),new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //do okay button stuff
                            }

                        });

    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(activity.getString(R.string.cancel),new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //do cancel button stuff
                            }

                        });
```

Comment: I have only setPositiveButtonText possibility. And not setPositiveButton

Comment: ah this is in the builder  AlertDialog.Builder when you create your dialog.  See the android documentation on passing those events back to the activity to deal with http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents

Answer (score 0):

No, you should use one of the other interfaces available in [`DialogInterface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html). For example, if you use [`DialogInterface.OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html), you'll receive a parameter in the callback telling you which button was clicked.

Comment: i already try with getDialog().setonClickListener() but is never fired.